# Gmail keyboard shortcut to insert image from URL?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to create a Gmail keyboard shortcut to insert an image from a URL?

Currently, it seems like doing so requires four steps:

1. Mouse over the paperclip icon for "Attach files"
2. Click on camera icon for "Insert photos"
3. Click on "Web address (URL)
4. Paste URL

Wouldn't it be nice to just hit, like, <kbd>⌘I</kbd> and be done with it?

Answer (score -2):

In the new version (of Inbox at least, I haven't testing on Gmail proper), just paste the photo URL into the body of the email.

Retraction: I accidentally copied the image itself instead of the URL. I'm a doofus.